# Message - "unknown error: cannot focus element" - in python selenium driver

Tags: python, selenium, search, selenium-webdriver

[image]

```html
<div id="ccodeinput">

 <input class="dropdownheader2" type="TEXT" name="CCODE" value="435435" size="14" maxlength="22">

 </div>
```

This is the code for the Search field(see screenshot - upper right side). I am unable to pass values from a list to this search bar. But I am able to press the search button beside it. 
How can I enter values in the search field?

This is what I have tried:

```
inputElement = chrome_driver.find_element_by_id('ccodeinput')
inputElement.send_keys(435435)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Pls provide the code used for which the error is thrown.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared the `<input>` tag is a child of `<div>` tag, so to put text within the intended element you can use :

```
chrome_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='dropdownheader2' and @name='CCODE']").send_keys("435435")
```